# Google Apps Premium Edition: which authentication mechanism to use?

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-authentication

Our company has a web application that is only used internally by our employees. We also have Google Apps Premier Edition. We would like to make it so our employees can log into our private web application using the Google Apps account that they already have.

**Requirements:** We want to display our own login form. We don't want to pass the email/password in plain text through the internet.

Which authentication mechanism should we use to achieve this?

Note: our application is written in PHP using Zend Framework (if that matters).

Answer (score 0):

I would look into some combination of OpenID and your domain users (i.e. only let those at domain.com can log in).

[Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html)

They also have libraries for PHP and other languages that you can leverage to make this happen.

EDIT:

[Some more info](http://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api/web/openid-discovery-for-hosted-domains)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to integrate Google Apps and an internally used private system, we simply have two options.

1. Use Google as the authentication center. Modify the private system to authenticate at Google's server. We could use OpenID or AuthSub. Check http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html and http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthSub.html for more information.
2. Use the private system as the authentication center. In this case, we have to implement SAML protocol in the private server and configure Google Apps's SSO settings. Check http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/saml_reference_implementation.html for more information.

It is easier to accomplish SSO with the first method since there's already bunch of OpenID libraries out there. But, as you described in the requirements, you want to use your own login form. So I guess you have to go with the second method.

BTW, if your private system has to get or set information from Google, you may want to use OAuth for authorization. See http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ClientLogin](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_developers_protocol.html#client_login) API, it does exactly what you're after: allow you to verify username and password.  (the link goes to provisioning API doco but that is not relevant here)

Pro's:

- you get to use you own login form

Cons:

- you don't get SSO with Google Apps, i.e. users already in Apps will be prompted to login again (you didn't mention that as a requirement, but it seems a reasonable thing to want)
- Google won't like you (they're trying to discourage ProgrammaticLogin.
- you will get occasional CAPTCHA tests you'll need to show your users.

OpenID specifically prevents you from displaying your own login page, so if that's a hard requirements, Programmatic Login is really your only choice.

Going the SSO route let's you do pretty much anything, but may be a bit of overkill to take on authentication for the whole domain to make one app authenticate in a nicer fashion?  If you really want to go down this route, check out SimpleSAMLphp.